# Simple HTML help

Tags: html

```
   <td>

   <img src="images/smlnkhome_01.gif" width="23" height="52" alt=""></td>
 <td colspan="3">
     <a href="google.com"><img src="images/smlnkhome_02.gif" width="87" height="52" alt=""></a></td>
  <td bgcolor="#151515"><a href="plan.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image37','','images/images/smlnkhome_03h_03.gif',1)"><img src="images/smlnkhome_03.gif" name="Image37" width="86" height="52" border="0"></a></td>
  <td><a href="inv.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image36','','images/images/smlnkhome_04h_04.gif',1)"><img src="images/smlnkhome_04.gif" name="Image36" width="110" height="52" border="0"></a></td>
  <td><a href="mm.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image38','','images/images/smlnkhome_05h_05.gif',1)"><img src="images/smlnkhome_05.gif" name="Image38" width="131" height="52" border="0"></a></td>
  <td colspan="3"><a href="dt.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image39','','images/images/smlnkhome_09h_06.gif',1)"><img src="images/smlnkhome_06.gif" name="Image39" width="110" height="52" border="0"></a></td>
  <td colspan="2"><a href="ctl.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image40','','images/images/smlnkhome_07h_07.gif',1)"><img src="images/smlnkhome_07.gif" name="Image40" width="136" height="52" border="0"></a></td>
  <td><a href="ts.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image41','','images/images/smlnkhome_08h_08.gif',1)"><img src="images/smlnkhome_08.gif" name="Image41" width="110" height="52" border="0"></a></td>

  <td><a href="proposal.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image42','','images/images/smlnkhome_09h_09.gif',1)"><img src="images/smlnkhome_09.gif" name="Image42" width="80" height="52" border="0"></a></td>
  <td><a href="review.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image43','','images/images/smlnkhome_10h_10.gif',1)"><img src="images/smlnkhome_10.gif" name="Image43" width="84" height="52" border="0"></a></td>
  <td>
```

Right, I'm trying the image "smlnkhome_02.gif" to link to google, but every time I enter in the code (manually and through dreamweaver), the row of buttons muck up...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F0uE.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Give `<img>` tag an attribute of `style="border:0px;"`

This should set it right

Comment: To be consistent, he should either use border="0" or change all of the other `img` tags style attributes, too.

Answer (score 2):

you should give the img with a link a border of zero;

so in your css:

```
a img {
border:0px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Good answer but why ad "solid black;"? Is it really necessary?

Comment: @Blake the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-properties) say it isn't.

Comment: It isn't necessary, I'm just used to do it? border:none; or border-width:0; will work too.

Answer (score 2):

To disable those pesky blue borders add this to a global CSS:

```
a img{
    border: none;
}
```

To learn more about CSS Reset and disabling unwanted default styles check out [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Tim and Alin.  If you want to save yourself some work, handle the blue borders globally using CSS:

```
a img {
   border:0px;
}
```

-OR-

If you just want to remove the border from a single image wrapped in a link:

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/smlnkhome_02.gif" style="border:0px;" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also it will be useful to read more about [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).